# How to typeset template attributes using TikzUml?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I've tried to typeset a template class attribute in Tikz Uml using the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzumlset{font=\footnotesize}

    \umlclass[x=0, y=0, type=abstract]{Class}{}{
        \umlvirt{+execute(): bool}
    }

    \umlclass[x=-3, y=-4]{DerivedClass}
    {
        -variable\_: type\\
        -variablePtr\_: smartPtr<variableType>
    }
    {
    }
    \umlVHVimpl[anchors=north and south]{DerivedClass}{Class}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And I got this as a result:

[image]

Instead of smartPtr¡variableType¿ I expected

```
smartPointer<variableType>
```

How do I get that? I tried escaping the "<" character, but I got the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\tikzumlClassAttributes ...riablePtr\_: smartPtr\<
                                                  variableType\> 
l.20     }
```

Answer (score 3):

Nobody answered so far, and I found that using \textless \textgreater gets rid of this issue in the meantime, so now this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzumlset{font=\footnotesize}

    \umlclass[x=0, y=0, type=abstract]{Class}{}{
        \umlvirt{+execute(): bool}
    }

    \umlclass[x=-3, y=-4]{DerivedClass}
    {
        -variable\_: type\\
        -variablePtr\_: smartPtr\textless variableType\textgreater
    }
    {
    }
    \umlVHVimpl[anchors=north and south]{DerivedClass}{Class}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

results with

[image]

Comment: It may be preferable to use the `T1` font-encoding and the `lmodern` fonts: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, I'll try this asap

Comment: Is it common to add these to the class header?  If so, I'm having trouble when I add them to an abstract class header.